# Query String or Bound Parameters in filtration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, query-string

I can filter products in my website in 2 ways:

`www.expamle.com/products?category=cars&brand=hot_wheels`
or :
`www.expamle.com/products/car/hot_wheels`

what is the best practice and why?

and if i applied the second solution, how can i know the type of the passed param is `category` or `brand`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it stays as is, second option, by far. Not only for elegance but for SEO.

That being said, the minute you'd start having a 3rd and 4rd argument, you clearly would need a search. Whether you chose to go with full text search or more like an advanced search with check boxes depends on your project. I tend to favour full-text search but if you want to stick to your design, and no more parameters would be added, here's what it could look like:

You will get the parameters based on the routes you set up.

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'products/:category/:brand', to: 'products#index'

# app/controllers/products_controller.rb
def index
  @products = Products.where(category: params[:category]).where(brand: params[:brand])
end
```

### Update

If both category and brand are optional and not dependent, you could join category and brand into a Tag model. Much more flexible. 'products(/:tag(/:tag(/:tag)))'.

Comment: I can have both category and brand or category only or brand only or not of both.
i can use:
match 'products(/:category(/:brand))" => "products#index"
but if the url is '/products/hot_wheels' how can i know that 'hot_wheels' is a brand not a category.

Comment: I solved that before by joining category and brand into a Tag model. Much more flexible. 'products(/:tag(/:tag(/:tag)))'. Otherwise, stick with your first option. It gives you more flexibility indeed.

Comment: Updated answer according to your preferred approach